# self.tableView.delegate = self and self.table.dataSource = self memory leak

Tags: iphone, delegates, datasource, memory-leaks, tableview

I have following codes, which have memory leak on device, could you please kindly help check it? Thanks.

```
@interface NewsListViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

@private
  UITableView *tableView;
  NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
......

}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end



@implementation NewsListViewController {

......

 - (void)dealloc {
    [fetchedResultsController release];
 fetchedResultsController = nil; 

    tableView.delegate = nil;
 tableView.dataSource = nil;
 [tableView release];
 tableView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
 }

 -(void)viewDidLoad {

......

  tableView.delegate = self;   // **leak here**

  tableView.dataSource = self; // **leak here**
  DemoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DemoAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(handleSaveNotification:)
         name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
          object:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
```

[self fetch];

```
}

- (void)fetch {
```

NSError *error = nil;
   BOOL success = [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
   if (!success) {
  debugLog(@"Unhandled error performing fetch: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  NSAssert1(0, @"Unhandled error performing fetch: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
   }
   [tableView reloadData];

```
}

 - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
```

if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

DemoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DemoAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" 
           inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext]];

fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                    managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext
                   sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                      cacheName:@"NewsCache"];

```
}
```

return fetchedResultsController;
     }

```
 - (void)handleSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
```

DemoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DemoAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   [appDelegate.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:aNotification];
   [self fetch];
     }

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    News *news = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // fill cell.label.text according to the news field value

 }   

 @end
```

Comment: What makes you think that this leaks? We need more code, and info about leaked objects.

Answer (score 1):

It is astronomically unlikely that setting the delegate or dataSource property of a UITableView instance could cause a noticeable memory leak.

You should examine your surrounding code more thoroughly.

Comment: @Eiko, Ryan, thanks for your reply, I added more detail code, I used core data to provide data for cell in tableView, I have no idea why the leak occurred. Could you please help check it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: More code is good, but there still isn't enough. You are releasing and retaining everything appropriately. As Eiko asked previously: what makes you think that this leaks? Have you used Instruments to check it?

Comment: yes, the instrument indicates that there is leak. But the responsible lib is UIKit instead of my app, can I ignore it? Thanks.